# Cost for a Wand / Ring / Whatever of Unlimited Prestidigitation?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

What would the value be of a wand / ring / whatever of prestidigitation that has unlimited charges and unlimited uses per day?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most convenient form would be a continuous wondrous item, something you could wear and it would constantly confer *prestidigitation* to you, as long as you wear it.

As a 0th-level spell (½ for the purposes of calculating costs) at caster level 1st, the guidelines would suggest a cost of ½ × 1 × 2,000 gp = 1,000 gp. Considering what *prestidigitation* is and isn’t allowed to do (i.e. it’s basically forbidden from doing anything intrinsically valuable, and can only provide usefulness by being creative about applying its limited powers), I’d personally say that’s a fair bit on the high end, but then it is a pretty open-ended and awesome spell (it’s not known as *the littlest wish* for nothing).

As always, the magic item creation guidelines are only guidelines; speak with your DM about the exact price.

Comment: I suggest the *hand of the mage* is a comparable magic item.

Comment: Hand of the Mage is arguably more powerful even, because Mage Hand has a much shorter duration that Prestidigitation.

Comment: 1k honestly sounds about right to me. The advantages of availability and ease of use are significant.