# A method of casting unlimited level 0 spells (cantrips?)

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, optimization

In D&D 3.5, is there any method of casting spells that fit in the lvl 0 spell slot without being limited to a number of times/day? The goal is to cast Prestigitation an unlimited amount of times/day due to the usefulness of turning people's hair hot pink. I am willing to take feats for this.

My character is at level 12 with 5 levels in factotum and 7 in chameleon.

Also, I believe I found a hint which is in some Therafirm Setting: http://therafim.wikidot.com/versatile-spellcaster

Which says: "Special: In Therafim once you gain Unlimited Cantrips you may still only sacrifice up to your normal daily allotment of cantrips to fuel this feat."

Comment: Are you playing a game on a Therafim channel, or, I guess, is your DM using the Therafim houserules?

Comment: I do not know, though. DM hasn't responded to said question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best method (as long as you can get your DM to agree) is probably a [custom magic item](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78263/15469).

From *Complete Arcane* (page 80), the feat Innate Spell allows you to cast one spell of your choice as many times/day as you like. However, it requires you to have the Quicken Spell, Silent Spell, and Still Spell feats, as well as permanently losing one of your 8th-level spell slots.

The D'hin race, from *Dragon Magazine* 350, page 56, get at-will *prestidigitation* - only a +1 level adjustment, which you may find easier to swallow.

While it won't let you **cast** *prestidigitation* an unlimited number of times per day, the metamagic feat Persistent Spell could be used to make a single casting of *prestidigitation* last 24 hours, allowing you to use its various effects all day. Unfortunately, this will require it to be cast from a 6th-level spell slot, so you'll have to look into [ways of reducing metamagic costs](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=972) (there are too many to list here, although Arcane Thesis is probably the simplest).

In the same vein as Persistent Spell, with your DM's permission, *permanency* could be used to give you a permanent *prestidigitation*, allowing you to use its effects whenever you want.

Comment: What if you are a level 7 chameleon and level 5 factotum with access of up to level 5 spells?

Comment: @garretLennelluc Then this won't work, obviously. If you have requirements (like that one) that you haven't included in the question, you should add them.

Comment: go with the custom magic item, then.

Comment: @nijineko That or permanency are definitely the cheapest options, but suffer from needing DM permission.